# filter rows based on all previous keeping groups of data R for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

I have a simple data frame where i would like to filter rows based on previous data but keeping groups of data by a given variable.

```
orig_df<-structure(list(New_ID = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "d", "d", "d"), New_ID.1 = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", 
"d", "c", "d", "e", "d", "e", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Below is current code which is close to what i need i think.

```
orig_df <- as.data.frame(orig_df)
included_rows <- rep(FALSE, nrow(orig_df))
seen_ids <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(orig_df)){
  # Skip row if we have seen either ID already
  #if(orig_df[i, 'New_ID']   %in% seen_ids) next
  if(orig_df[i, 'New_ID.1'] %in% seen_ids) next
  # If both ids are new, we save them as seen and include the entry
  seen_ids <- c(seen_ids, orig_df[i, 'New_ID'] , orig_df[i, 'New_ID.1'] )
  included_rows[i] <-  TRUE
}
filtered_df <- orig_df[included_rows,]
```

I need the code to filter out "b" and "c" since they are in "a" group first in New.Id.1 first, order matters here and my table is arranged. Since "d" in New_ID is not in variable "a" of New_ID.1 **and** b and c have been filtered, it should be kept. Final table should be this:

```
structure(list(New_ID = c("a", "a", "a", "d", "d", "d"), New_ID.1 = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

a|a
a|b
a|c
d|d
d|e
d|f
```

Hope that made sense!

thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if i need to rename the variables to include a count, for example "a_1", "a_2", "a_3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is what you want:

```
included_rows <- rep(FALSE, nrow(orig_df))
seen_ids <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(orig_df)){
    # Skip row if first seen in other valid group
    if(orig_df[i, "New_ID"] %in% seen_ids) next
    # Add row to seen IDs if it is grouped with a different letter
    if (orig_df[i,"New_ID"] != orig_df[i,"New_ID.1"]) {
        seen_ids <- append(seen_ids, orig_df[i,"New_ID.1"])
    }
    included_rows[i] <- TRUE
}
filtered_df <- orig_df[included_rows,]
```

Probably not the most efficient way to do it, but this will filter out rows where the first appearance of New_ID is as New_ID.1 when New_ID and New_ID.1 are different, with appearances in that situation only mattering if the row hasn't already been filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the order matters and the table is arranged. Is it arranged alphabetically like your example? If so, you could use a `group_by` function and find the minimum value of New_ID for every New_ID.1.

```
library(tidyverse)
orig_df %>%
  group_by(New_ID.1) %>%
  summarise(New_ID.2 = min(New_ID))
```

You might need to change the column names though.

Comment: That doesn't match quite what i need. I need to keep "a" and "d" in New_ID column while removing b and c in New_ID since they are present in New_ID.1 of group a.

Comment: Also the table is arranged in correct order.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.